# TYPO3 extbase fluid: nested object in loop

Tags: loops, nested, typo3, fluid, extbase

I have in a Object (dailysale) multiple nested elements (cashpoints) which contain again nested elements

**dailysale -> cashpoints -> sales**

```
      -> diffkinds -> sales
```

...

(where "cashpoint" holds the name and "sales" holds the actual in and out, 
diffkinds holds some additional which have sales too )
now I want to create a input/edit-form 
In the partial to edit the dailysafe I've a loop:

```
    {cashpoint.uid}<br>
    <f:form.textfield property="cashpoints.{cashpoint.uid}.was" value="{cashpoint.name}" /><br />
    <f:form.hidden property="cashpoints.{cashpoint.uid}.__identity" value="{cashpoint.uid}"/>

    <f:form.textfield property="cashpoints.{cashpoint.uid}.einnahme" value="{dailysale.cashpoints[cashpoint.uid][einnahme]}" /><br />
    <f:debug title="cashpointdebug1">{cashpoint}</f:debug>
    <f:debug title="cashpointdebug2">{tagesumsatz.cashpoints[cashpoint.uid]}</f:debug>

    <f:form.textfield property="cashpoints.{cashpoint.uid}.ausgabe" value="{cashpoint.ausgabe}"/><br />
```

updating the name of the different cashpoints works, but I don'nt get any access to the nested sales.
cashpointdebug1 gives me the actual cashpoint and as nested the sale,
but if I want to access cashpoint.sales or cashpoint.sales.input (a property) I get null.

What did I miss to access the nested object sales in the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I dont see any loop in your code, I assume you're looping through `{tagesumsatz.cashpoints}`. You need another loop to access the deeper nested objects.

```
<f:for each="{tagesumsatz.cashpoints}" as="cashpoint">
    <f:for each="{cashpoint.sales}" as="sale" >
        Here you can access each {sale.input} ...
    </f:for>
</f:for>
```